# How to estimate the progress of a GridSearchCV from verbose output in Scikit-Learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, parameters, scikit-learn, grid-search

Right now I'm running a pretty aggressive grid search.  I have `n=135 samples` and I am running `23 folds` using a custom cross-validation train/test list. I have my `verbose=2`.

The following is what I ran:

```
param_test = {"loss":["deviance"],
           'learning_rate':[0.01, 0.025, 0.05, 0.075, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2],
           "min_samples_split": np.linspace(0.1, 0.5, 12),
           "min_samples_leaf": np.linspace(0.1, 0.5, 12),
           "max_depth":[3,5,8],
          "max_features":["log2","sqrt"],
          "min_impurity_split":[5e-6, 1e-7, 5e-7],
          "criterion": ["friedman_mse",  "mae"],
           "subsample":[0.5, 0.618, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 1.0],
          "n_estimators":[10]}

Mod_gsearch = GridSearchCV(estimator = GradientBoostingClassifier(),
                           param_grid = param_test, scoring="accuracy",n_jobs=32, iid=False, cv=cv_indices, verbose=2)
```

I took a look at the verbose output in `stdout`:

```
$head gridsearch.o8475533
Fitting 23 folds for each of 254016 candidates, totalling 5842368 fits
```

Based on this, it looks like there are `5842368` permutations of cross-validation pairs using my grid params.

```
$ grep -c  "[CV]" gridsearch.o8475533
7047332
```

It looks like there are around 7 million cross-validations that have been done so far but that's more than the `5842368` total fits...

```
7047332/5842368 = 1.2062458236
```

Then when I look at the `stderr` file:

```
$ cat ./gridsearch.e8475533
[Parallel(n_jobs=32)]: Done 132 tasks      | elapsed:    1.2s
[Parallel(n_jobs=32)]: Done 538 tasks      | elapsed:    2.8s
[Parallel(n_jobs=32)]: Done 1104 tasks      | elapsed:    4.8s
[Parallel(n_jobs=32)]: Done 1834 tasks      | elapsed:    7.9s
[Parallel(n_jobs=32)]: Done 2724 tasks      | elapsed:   11.6s
...
[Parallel(n_jobs=32)]: Done 3396203 tasks      | elapsed: 250.2min
[Parallel(n_jobs=32)]: Done 3420769 tasks      | elapsed: 276.5min
[Parallel(n_jobs=32)]: Done 3447309 tasks      | elapsed: 279.3min
[Parallel(n_jobs=32)]: Done 3484240 tasks      | elapsed: 282.3min
[Parallel(n_jobs=32)]: Done 3523550 tasks      | elapsed: 285.3min
```

*My goal:*

**How can I know the progress of my gridsearch with respect to the total time it may take?**

*What I'm confused about:*

**What is the relationship between `[CV]` lines in `stdout`, total # of fits in `stdout`, and tasks in `stderr`?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Math is simple, but a little misleading at a first sight:

1. When each task is started logging mechanism yields a '[CV] ...' line to `stdout` noting about `starting` of execution and after task `ends` - another line with the addition of spent time for a particular task (in the end of the line).
2. Additionally, with some time intervals, logging mechanism writes a progress bar to `stderr` (or if you set `verbose` to >50 to `stdout`) indicating a number of completed task out of total tasks (fits) and total currently spent time, like that one:

   `[Parallel(n_jobs=32)]: Done 2724 tasks             | elapsed:   11.6s`

For your case, you have `5842368` total fits, i.e. tasks.

You counted `7047332` of '[CV] ...' which is `around 7047332/2 = 3523666` finished tasks and progress bar shows `exactly` how many tasks are completed -  3523550 (around - because some tasks could start, but not end at the time of counting).